# MySQL select date, join statistic data - how?

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I have some statistics I need to report on a monthly basis.  I need my query to return 0's for statistics which aren't there.  The only way I know to do this is to use SQL to generate a list of days within the specified time period and `LEFT JOIN` the statistic data that I need to report on.

Problem is.... I've never not selected from a table like that... how do I do that?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693320/sql-date-rows-for-inactivity-days, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-either, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670183/displaying-zero-valued-months-with-sql, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using SQL to pull the data I have for the given period and handling everything else on the PHP side.  Not exactly what I wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your returned values, for statistic that never existed your returned value probably will be null, all you need to compare returned value with null and if null return 0 otherwise return real result

```
select s.Name , IFNULL(d.Value, 0) as Value
 from Statustic s
LEFT JOIN t_Data d on (d.Stat_ID=s.ID)
```

and you can use this link to read more at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull

Answer (score 0):

If the values are *NULL* use

```
SELECT IFNULL( statistic, 0 ) AS statistic FROM myTable;
```