# MySQL to fill in missing dates when using GROUP BY DATE(table.timestamp) without joining on temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, gaps-and-islands

after reading through a couple similar Qs/As I haven't quite found the solution I'm looking for. The table data I have is GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) and returning a count, example result:

```
[timestamp] => 2010-05-12 20:18:36
[count] => 10


[timestamp] => 2010-05-14 10:10:10
[count] => 8
```

Without using a temporary table, or calendar table is there a way to fill in those missing dates? so that with the same table data would return:

```
[timestamp] => 2010-05-12 20:18:36
[count] => 10


/**
 * I would like to have this row added:
 */
[timestamp] => 2010-05-13 00:00:00
[count] => 0

[timestamp] => 2010-05-14 10:10:10
[count] => 8
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select All Dates In a Range Even If No Records Present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046865/mysql-select-all-dates-in-a-range-even-if-no-records-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the exact solution i was looking for, but I think found a method that works enough for my needs. I created a traffic table where the first visitor of the day will trigger a row insert for the day and now I can join on this table to get a daily record of whatever. The only problem however, is if there is no traffic for a day that date won't exist in the table. This can be solved by running a daily cron to insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to find the missing results on the client side and add them when you present the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a tally table (only 1 column: date), and fill it beforehand. 
You can run a cron script to fill 1 year, and run it once a year.