# Include a WHERE clause in a date query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm following the excellent solution from Guido concerning date queries where a given date may not be present in the database https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378448/6591500.

I've got the solution working as is without any issues. I now need expand with this to include a WHERE clause. I have a 'date' column and a 'results' column, I need to count the number of 'passes' on each given day in the results column.

My SQL is this:

```
SELECT report_date, COUNT(*)-1 AS the_tally FROM (
SELECT date(report_date) as report_date FROM data as t1
WHERE 'spf_result' = 'pass'
UNION ALL 
    SELECT curdate() - interval a day AS report_date FROM (
        select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3 union
        select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union
        select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union
        select 12 union select 13 union select 14 
    ) as t2 
) as t3 GROUP BY report_date ORDER BY report_date DESC LIMIT 14
```

The result I'm expecting is:

```
report_date   The_tally
2020-06-11       4
2020-06-10       4
2020-06-09       6
2020-06-08       4
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
report_date   The_tally
2020-06-11       0
2020-06-10       0
2020-06-09       0
2020-06-08       0
```

Example data is:

```
report_date   spf_result
2020-06-11       pass
2020-06-11       pass
2020-06-11       pass
2020-06-11       pass
2020-06-10       pass
2020-06-10       pass
2020-06-10       pass
2020-06-10       pass
2020-06-09       pass
etc...
```

Why am I getting zeros?

Comment: This will filter out all records: `WHERE 'spf_result' = 'pass'`, leaving you with zero results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two strings.

so you have to use backticks

Read also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

```
SELECT report_date, COUNT(*)-1 AS the_tally FROM (
SELECT date(report_date) as report_date FROM data as t1
WHERE `spf_result` = 'pass'
UNION ALL 
    SELECT curdate() - interval a day AS report_date FROM (
        select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3 union
        select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union
        select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11 union
        select 12 union select 13 union select 14 
    ) as t2 
) as t3 GROUP BY report_date ORDER BY report_date DESC LIMIT 14
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query the first part does not return any rows, the result of this:

```
SELECT date(report_date) as report_date FROM data as t1
WHERE 'spf_result' = 'pass'
```

is empty because `'spf_result' = 'pass'` is never True.

P.S. I do think you mean: `WHERE spf_result = 'pass'`

Comment: Those are probably meant to be back ticks.  I'm not smart enough to make them show up in a comment...

Comment: Backticks are only needed if you use reserved words for fieldnames (which you should not do)

Comment: test backticks `\`comment`   This is, between backticks a backslash, a backtick and  the word 'comment'.

Comment: Backticks. I hadnt noticed both sides had single quotes. I was thinking I'd got the WHERE clause in the wrong location. Its always the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your query WHERE 'spf_result' = 'pass' change to spf_result='pass'
spf_result is your column and your query compare two string and both string are different so your count in "The tally" show 0 because condition('spf_result' = 'pass') return false

i tried in sqlfiddle with given by your example data

DDL :-

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (rdate date,
    status varchar(20)
    );

INSERT INTO Table1
(rdate,status)
VALUES ('2020-06-11','Passed'),('2020-06-11','Passed'),('2020-06-11','Passed'),('2020-06-11','Passed'),('2020-06-10','Passed'),('2020-06-10','Passed'),('2020-06-09','Passed'),('2020-06-10','Passed')
;
```

Query :-

```
select rdate,count(*)AS tally from table1 group by rdate order by rdate desc
```

Output :- [image]