# Put 0 in arraylist if no record in table (SQLite) using JDBC by checking resultSet

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, arraylist, resultset

I know there are similar threads for same title, but my question addresses different point. I am checking resultSet to see

*whether query returns any value from `rating` column if yes take the value and add it to `arraylist` if no add `0.0` into arraylist(ratings)*.

In my code , else never gets executed resulting into no 0.0 in arraylist(for missing dates).Is my query going wrong somewhere? Please help.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE (dateofday BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND id = ?";
    String mediapath = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, Controller.id_logged_in);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, datepickerfrom.getValue().toString());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, datepickerto.getValue().toString());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        boolean flag = true;
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            do {
                ratings.add(resultSet.getFloat("rating"));
                countofday++;
            }
            while (resultSet.next());
        } else {
            ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        connection.close();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily, I am using this *inefficient* way by querying for every date . No choice.

```
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date1 = datepickerfrom.getValue().toString();
    String date2 = datepickerto.getValue().toString();
    try {
        Date d1 = myFormat.parse(date1);
        Date d2 = myFormat.parse(date2);

        while( d1.before(d2) ){
            d1 = addDays(d1, 1);
            allDates.add(d1);
            allDatesString.add(formatter.format(d1));
        }
        //System.out.println(allDatesString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < allDatesString.size(); i++) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE dateofday  = ? AND id = ?";
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, Controller.id_logged_in);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, allDatesString.get(i));
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if(resultSet.next())
                ratings.add(resultSet.getFloat("rating"));
            else
                ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

it gives :

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.505962, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.734242, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.67128, 0.0, 5.054585, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: re: *"No choice."* - That's silly. You are already taking the trouble to create an `allDates` list; you could just as easily create a `Map<String, Float>` with the dates as the keys and the values initialized to zero, loop through the original ResultSet to fill in the values, and then use `Arrays.asList(dateMap.values().toArray(new Float[0]))` to convert the map's values into an ArrayList.

Comment: @GordThompson yeah i could do that too..but my main q was how to do it without looping for every date and doing with one query using between.

Comment: *"how to do it ... with one query using between"* - That is what I meant when I said to loop through "the original ResultSet".

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    do {
        ratings.add(resultSet.getFloat("rating"));
        countofday++;
    }
    while (resultSet.next());
} else {
    ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));
}
```

If you have at least a result in the resultSet, you iterate over all results but you never enter in  `ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));` because you enter in only if you have not result.

The first conditional statement should be removed : `if (resultSet.next()) {`.
You should test the value returned by `resultSet.getFloat("rating")`.
If it is not null, do  `ratings.add(resultSet.getFloat("rating"));` otherwise do
`ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));`.

For example :

```
while (resultSet.next());
    float ratingObj = resultSet.getFloat("rating");
    if (!resultSet.wasNull()){
       ratings.add(ratingObj);
       countofday++;
    }
    else{
       ratings.add(Float.valueOf(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still printing `[9.505962, 7.734242, 9.67128, 5.054585]` even though daterange is of 26 days

Comment: i guess query is wrong .not sure though , this is what i want but can't understand/convert in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046865/mysql-select-all-dates-in-a-range-even-if-no-records-present