# MySQL: Generate decreasing daily work_hours at a constant pace

Tags: mysql

I have this query to extract `total_hours`, `start_date` and `end_date`:

```
select proj.start_date, proj.end_date, sum(ifnull(work.hours_estimate,0)) as total_hours
from project_table proj
left outer join project_task work on
    work.project_id = proj.id
where proj.id = 3
```

This query gives me a single row of result:

```
 start_date |   end_date    | total_hour
----------------------------------------
2017-04-24  |   2017-05-15  |   119
```

What I want is to generate a daily interval of rows, constantly decreasing the `total_hours` by a certain amount, say 19 hours, and the day increasing by 1 day.

Expected results:

```
    day     |  hours_left
------------------------
2017-04-24  |  119
2017-04-25  |  100
2017-04-26  |  81
2017-04-27  |  62
2017-04-28  |  43
2017-04-29  |  24
```

... and so on and so forth until it reaches 2017-05-15 (of course, no negative for hours_left, just zero if negative)

can't seem to figure out how to do this.

***QUESTIONS:***

> 1.) Is this possible in MySQL?
>
> 2.) If this is possible in MySQL, is it efficient/convinient?

If not, I could just do it in application, as state in the comments

Comment: Consider handling such issues in application code.

Comment: so this is not posible in mysql? ill edit my question then.

Comment: All things are possible. Some things are sensible.

Comment: well, you got me there. post your comments as answer, ill accept.

Comment: This is a lot more easier to achieve in the application layer. SQL language in general is not really great at creating new records on the fly. It can be done, but it will be ugly.

Comment: dudes, your comments are good enough to be answers.

Comment: Just to show you that we know what we are talking about, I will provide already existing SO answers to the two fundamental parts of your question: 1) fill gaps in a date range 2) cumulative sum (in this case, cumulative minus) You need to combine the two in order to get what you are looking for.

Comment: filling gaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31141256/5389997

Comment: cumulative sum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql