# Search by date even if date is not in table

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, where-clause, records

I make a select in MySQL and  search between 2 dates and make a count of elements by date and it works fine but, if a date has no records it does not appear, what I'm looking for is something like this:

Column date  /    Count

- 2017-01-01 /   1
- 2017-01-02 /   2
- 2107-01-03 /    0     *Date without records
- 2017-01-04 /     1

What I get

- 2017-01-01 /   1
- 2017-01-02 /   2
- 2017-01-04 /   1

2017-01-03 does not show because has no records

Query:

```
SELECT I.FechaInstalacion, count(Case when I.ServicioId = 1 then 1 end) as P
FROM Instalacion I
WHERE I.EmpleadoId = 4 and I.FechaInstalacion>='2018-01-01' and 
I.FechaInstalacion<= '2018-01-31'
group by I.FechaInstalacion
```

Thank you!

Comment: how can you get a record, which doesn't exists in table ???

Comment: sounds like you need another table with all dates and left join that table.

Comment: Or simply make the assumption that when a date is missing from the results that there are no rows for that date, which is true.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select All Dates In a Range Even If No Records Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046865/mysql-select-all-dates-in-a-range-even-if-no-records-present)