# Summarize by week with COUNT of two date columns

Tags: mysql, date, calendar

I want to summarize some COUNT data by week. The week starts on Sunday. The query must account for weeks where the COUNT is 0. The counts are on two dates. A referral date and the service date. All I want to do is count the number of referrals for each week and how many service dates there are in the same week. These two COUNTS are not linked. A referral may come in 1 week but the service get done another week.

My attempt: 
1) I created a calendar table with a entry for each day for the period I am working. The date entries cover more than the period being used.
2) I have a field in my Select that summarizes by 'Week Beginning'
3) I have COUNT fields on each of the date fields (Referral, Visits). Note that I use Distinct because there are multiple service codes for a visit but I only need to count them as 1.

Here is the code:

```
select
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(calendar.datefield) - MOD(TO_DAYS(calendar.datefield) -1, 7)),'%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS `Week Beginning`,

COUNT(DISTINCT opsData.`Patient Last Name`, opsData.`Patient First Name`, opsData.Discipline, opsData.`Referral Date`) as `Referrals`,

COUNT(DISTINCT opsData.`Patient Last Name`, opsData.`Patient First Name`, opsData.`Date of Service`) as Visits

from opsdata RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`) = calendar.datefield)

where (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`)) FROM opsdata) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`)) FROM opsdata))
group by `Week Beginning`
order by `Week Beginning` ASC
```

---

The problem i'm having is that I can only get 1 of the COUNTS to be accurate at a time based on the RIGHT JOIN. If I use DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`) then the Referral COUNT is correct and the Visits is wrong. If I use DATE(opsData.`Date of Service`) then the Visits is correct and the Referral COUNT is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the earlies / latest date of the 2 fields. You can use [least() and greatest() functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) to achieve this:

```
...BETWEEN (SELECT least(MIN(DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`)),min(date(opsData.`Date of Service`))) FROM opsdata)
   AND (SELECT greatest(MAX(DATE(opsData.`Referral Date`)), max(date(opsData.`Date of Service`))) FROM opsdata))
```

Comment: I got the same result with the new code you recommended. To run a test to see if the where clause is the issue I changed it to:                                calendar.datefield >= date('2016/01/01') and calendar.datefield <= date('2016/06/10') and I got the same result as with your code and my original code.

Comment: In this case you need to provide sample data, actual output you receive from your query and expected outcome as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question recently on [MySQL: multiple count in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652402/mysql-multiple-count-in-one-row/37655389?noredirect=1#comment62791893_37655389)

What you basically need to do is generate a list of weeks.
If you want week commencing and a date as the groups then you can use.

```
(SELECT date(adddate(datetime, INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(datetime) DAY)) as week
FROM (
    select (curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) Week) as datetime
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) AS t
where datetime > '2016' -- enter your earliest year here
ORDER BY datetime ASC) week_list
```

Then what you do is left join queries of counts that you want.
    ie

```
(select date_format(timestamp,'%X-%V') theweek, count(id) from table where ______ group by theweek) on week_list.week=table.theweek
```

NB that the formats of the join have to match if you get what I mean.

Any issues let me know. But hopefully this and the previous post helps you out.

Brett