# GROUP BY date with no leaks SQL on MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5, mysql-5.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-either)

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `trb3` (
  `value` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `date` date default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 


SELECT date, SUM(value) AS value FROM trb3 GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

but

```
  Jun 30 2011,100
  Jun 29 2011,90
      .
      .
  Jun 10 2011,90
  Jun 02 2011,89
  Jun 01 2011,10
```

Why Jun 03 data is not appear?

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have data for Jun 03? If not, Jun 03 will not appear in results - only actual data will appear

Comment: no I don't have a data of Jun 03 , but I'd like to get "0" data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get a list of the dates you want then outer join with it:

```
create table my_dates (my_date date not NULL);
```

then populate my_dates with the dates you want data for:

```
insert into my_dates values ('2011-06-01'), ('2011-06-02'), ...;
```

then

```
select my_dates.date, SUM(value)
from my_dates left join trb3 on trb3.date = my_dates.my_date
group by 1;
```

EDIT:
FYI, this is not intended to be a temporary table, it's a permanent table.

Comment: Thank you so much. but I don't wanna create table. Can I solve without temporaly tables?

Comment: @freddiefujiwara: If you don't want to solve this with a temporary table, then solve it with a persistent table. A number table could come in handy in many different cases. You could create one and use it in this particular problem for creating a contiguous list of dates within the range that matches your criteria.

Comment: Yes there are other ways to solve the problem - it just happens that this is the **right** one