# SQL count stays per day query not working as expected

Tags: php, sql

Let's assume I manage medical patient stays information system.

I want to get the patient count per day with the following minimal structure :

- `stay` table has `begin` and `end` datetime columns
- PHP gives me `$first_day` and `$last_day` limits

The following snippet is NOT what I want, since it only counts entries per day, and not present stays per day:

```sql
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`stay`.`begin`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`, 
  COUNT(`stay`.`stay_id`) AS `total`
FROM `stay`
WHERE `stay`.`begin` <= '$first_day'
  AND `stay`.`end`   >= '$last_day'
GROUP BY `date` 
ORDER BY `date`
```

Last but not least, I'm looking for a full SQL query.

It goes without saying that making one SQL query for each day would be totally trivial.

Use of temporary (dates ?) table is clearly an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned using a temporary table of all dates in the range you want is one way to handle this. If you created a table of date called `foo` with all dates between `$first_day`  and `$last_day` inclusive (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75928/21644)).

Then you can write your query like:

```
SELECT f.date, count(s.stay_id)
FROM foo f
JOIN stay s ON s.begin <= f.date AND s.end >= date
GROUP BY f.date
ORDER BY f.date
```

Comment: Ok I feel kind of stupid now, I should have found (a) the query, (b) the stack thread you linked. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: One more thing, is casting my datetimes into dates necessary? I don't think so.

Comment: In the select, or in the table? Additionally if you don't want a stored procedue you could also create a calendar table with all dates up until 2100, and just join that a use your begin/end.

Comment: I meant in the select. For dates table, I was considering building it on demand, PHP side, but I guess having a dates table ready to use is much more efficient et prevents from using temporary tables.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google around leads me to this page: [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe)

What I would suggest is that you either follow the advice in that question, or construct your own loop in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll prefer looping with PHP tools. Not so fond of stored procedures concept.