# Show all the day and date regardless of existence of records

Tags: mysql, select

I'm not sure if it's possible in MySQL.
I want to show "Log" table below[image]

Like this format
[image]

Unlike the first table, all the date are shown on the second table including holidays and weekday.
I've tried to search in Google but i don't know the term of what i'm trying to do.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you got any initial SQL? I'm having a hard time to understand what exactly you need.

Comment: If you want want output rows, even for dates which don't exist in your data, the common way is to create a calendar table and join on that.  See this question and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/q/75752/302243

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(TIME_ENTER),DATE(TIME_ENTER),DEPT_NAME AS DEPARTMENT,NAME,TIME(TIME_ENTER) AS TIME_IN,TIME(TIME_EXIT) AS TIME_OUT FROM Log;
```

You would need a second table for holidays to cross compare for highlighting as Holidays are different in different countries.