# Return 'properties' with ANY availability between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have been searching and experimenting with this for 2 days and am unable to get it to work properly and am really hoping for some help.

**cabins**

```
cabin_id
name
active
start_day  (enum 'Saturday' or 'Sunday')
```

**bookings**

```
booking_id
cabin_id
check_in   (date)
check_out  (date)
confirmed
```

So far pretty simple.  I should note that cabin rentals are only in 1 week blocks and the week either starts on a Saturday or Sunday.

I need to return all of the 'cabins' that have **ANY** availability between two dates, not that **ARE** available between two dates as with most reservation system answers I've seen on here.

My attempt so far:

```
SELECT c.cabin_id, c.name
FROM cabin c
WHERE (c.cabin_id NOT IN (
  SELECT b.cabin_id 
  FROM bookings b 
  WHERE (b.check_out >= '$date_from' && b.check_in <= '$date_to') OR 
        (b.check_out <= '$date_from' && b.check_in >= '$date_to')
  )
)
ORDER BY `c`.`order` ASC
```

This only shows the cabins which have **no bookings** at all between the two dates.

For example I added a booking from Jan 26, 2014 to March 2, 2014 and this query will not show the cabin in January, February or March where it **should** show it in January and March as it has some availability still in those months.

I've worked myself around in a loop now and can't seem to get my head around this.

**EDIT**
SQL Fiddle with tables and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3c8f/3

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output, preferably in a form of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Yep: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3c8f/3 ... This query should return all 3 properties in the cabins table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe

Comment: Thanks Marcus ... although I'm not really sure how that helps me?