# mysql join two table rows in one table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables e_sku and e_availability, In e_sku table i have 45 rows with the default availability as 1, below is an example

```
id  is_available    name
1   1               UN001N
2   1               UN002N
3   1               UN003N
4   1               UN004N
5   1               UN005N
6   1               UN006N
7   1               UN007N
8   1               UN008N
9   1               UN009N
10  1               UN010N
11  1               UN011N
12  1               UN012N
13  1               UN013N
14  1               UN014N
15  1               UN015N
16  1               UN016N
17  1               UN017N
18  1               UN018N
19  1               UN019N
20  1               UN020N
21  1               UN021N
22  1               UN022N
23  1               UN023N
24  1               UN024N
25  1               UN025N
26  1               UN026N
27  1               UN027N
28  1               UN028N
29  1               UN029N
30  1               UN030N
31  1               UN031N
32  1               UN032N
33  1               UN033N
34  1               UN034N
35  1               UN035N
36  1               UN036N
37  1               UN037N
38  1               UN038N
39  1               UN039N
40  1               UN040N
41  1               UN041N
42  1               UN042N
43  1               UN043N
44  1               UN044N
45  1               UN045N
```

Second table is e_availability in this table i am only storing the unavailability with dates below is the example

```
id  e_sku_id    is_available    working_date
1   5           0               10/20/2016
2   8           0               10/20/2016
3   10          0               10/20/2016
4   1           0               10/20/2016
5   15          0               10/20/2016
6   11          0               10/19/2016
7   1           0               10/19/2016
```

Because the data is capturing every date for unavailability so i am only gathering the unavailable product's data in e_availability table w.r.t. dates, Now i am looking to show the data for each day as complete skus in such a way that every day report will show 45 skus and for available sku it will show 1 from e_sku table's column is_available and for unavailable sku it will show the column of is_availability from e_availability table

I am using mysql database, I tried many join queries but not getting the report.
 can any one guide about which join i require

I got the result by using this query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,NAME,1 AS is_available FROM e_sku
WHERE company_id = 2
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT e_sku.id,e_sku.name, edge_availability.is_available FROM edge_availability
JOIN edge_working ON edge_working.`id` = edge_availability.`working_id`
JOIN e_sku ON e_sku.id = edge_availability.`sku_id`
WHERE edge_working.`working_date` = '2016-10-19' AND edge_availability.`store_id` = 84) X)
UNION
SELECT e_sku.id,e_sku.name, edge_availability.is_available FROM edge_availability
JOIN edge_working ON edge_working.`id` = edge_availability.`working_id`
JOIN e_sku ON e_sku.id = edge_availability.`sku_id`
WHERE edge_working.`working_date` = '2016-10-19' AND edge_availability.`store_id` = 84) Y
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to detect when a date isn't found in the `e_availability` table. The join will return `NULL` for all the columns in that table, then you can default to the value from `e_sku`.

```
SELECT d.date, s.id, IFNULL(a.is_available, s.is_available) AS is_available
FROM all_dates AS d
CROSS JOIN e_sku AS s
LEFT JOIN e_availability ON d.working_date = a.date AND s.id = a.e_sku_id
```

You need to create an additional table `all_dates` that contains all the dates that you want to report on. See [What is the most straightforward way to pad empty dates in sql results (on either mysql or perl end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe) for how you can create such a table dynamically.